# Finding asymptotic behaviour

Tags: brownian-motion

I have a problem in finding the asymptotic behavior of this sum: 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigl|B^2 (t_{i+1})-B^2 (t_i)\bigr|$$ over $[0,T]$ when $h= t_{i+1}-t_i \to 0$ and $B$ is Brownian motion.

The following is how far I got with this problem. First, I consider:

\begin{align*}
\bigl|B^2 (t_{i+1})-B^2 (t_i)\bigr|
&=\bigl|[B (t_{i+1})-B (t_i)][B (t_{i+1})+B (t_i)]\bigr|\\
&=\bigl|[B (t_{i+1})-B (t_i)]^2 + 2 B(t_i)[B (t_{i+1})-B (t_i)]\bigr| \\
&\quad<\bigr|[B (t_{i+1})-B (t_i)]^2|+|2 B(t_i)[B (t_{i+1})-B(t_i)]\bigr|
\end{align*}
I can show that sum of the first element goes to $T$ when $h \to 0$, but I can't find asymptotic behavior of the second element (I tried to show that it will go to infinity). Also, I need to find the lower bound of this in order to show that  $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigl|B^2 (t_{i+1})-B^2 (t_i)\bigr|$ goes to infinity.
Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hey, Doc. You punched up a bunch of good $\TeX$ math, but you forgot the dollar signs. It won't work too well without 'em!

Comment: opss, sorry for my stupid mistake and thanks for fixing it ^^